# Get the maximum consecutive null rows in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame where i need to obtain the bigger sequence of null rows by start and end dates for further study. My index is a DatatimeIndex object and the DataFrame looks like this:

```
                           C Instalation  N Serial Number D Register Read  \
Z Ts Read                                                                    
2016-12-25 00:00:00  PT0002000080299561BD   10101516046456              A+   
2016-12-25 00:15:00  PT0002000080299561BD   10101516046456              A+   
2016-12-25 00:30:00  PT0002000080299561BD   10101516046456              A+   
2016-12-25 00:45:00  PT0002000080299561BD   10101516046456              A+   
2016-12-25 01:00:00  PT0002000080299561BD   10101516046456              A+   

                    M Read D Read Unit  
Z Ts Read                               
2016-12-25 00:00:00  0,002         kWh  
2016-12-25 00:15:00  0,002         kWh  
2016-12-25 00:30:00  0,002         kWh  
2016-12-25 00:45:00  0,002         kWh  
2016-12-25 01:00:00  0,002         kWh
```

The NaN values can be scattered throughout the **columns** dataframe, no problem. But i do mind if they are consecutive. And in that case i would want to know for each row having atleast one NaN value, the start and end `index` and calculate the range difference between the two. In the end i want to get the bigger range.

Is possible to do this?

Comment: maybe `dropna` and check for the gaps in `Z Ts Read`?

Comment: Dropping the NaN values i am creating a disruption in the sequence of the timestamps but im getting some hard time getting the `delta` time.. :/

Comment: Can you give an example of how the output would look like, please? I can't get my head around what you mean by bigger sequence of null rows by start and end dates.

Comment: Thank you @pansen. I already edited the question. Is it ok?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand the Q 100% but maybe this is what you want:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 7, 8], "b": [1, 2, 3, np.nan, 5, 6, 7, 8]}

print df

     a    b
0  1.0  1.0
1  2.0  2.0
2  3.0  3.0
3  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  5.0
5  NaN  6.0
6  7.0  7.0
7  8.0  8.0

counts = df.isnull()
counts[~counts] = np.nan
print counts

    a    b
0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN
3  1.0  1.0
4  1.0  NaN
5  1.0  NaN
6  NaN  NaN
7  NaN  NaN

runs = counts.cumsum()
print runs

     a    b
0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN
3  1.0  1.0
4  2.0  NaN
5  3.0  NaN
6  NaN  NaN
7  NaN  NaN

runs.max(axis=0)

a    3.0
b    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: If this answer didn't solve your problem, check out [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/22105/84387) one. Combining both of these ideas can solve a lot of problems.